# Не переходит в товар при нажатии кнопки select options

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, select

Сайт на вордпресс. https://emi-school.ca/shop/e-milacs/page/4/ есть кнопка "select options" - в самой кнопке заложена ссылка перехода на товар, но когда нажимаешь, переход не осуществляется, но если нажимать правой кнопки мышки открыть в новой вкладке, страница открывается.
А нужно чтобы страница открывалась при нажатии на кнопку "select options". В чем может быть проблема, и как это можно устранить.

Answer (score 0):

Можно попытаться исправить js ошибку

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: psfw_object_name is not defined
```

Но если ошибка не смущает, то можно самостоятельно обрабатывать клик и отправлять на товар

Вставьте где-нибудь внизу страницы

```
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery( document ).on( 'click', 'a.product_type_variable', function(event) {
            
                event.preventDefault();
                
                location.href = jQuery(this).attr('href');
                
                return false;
    });
});
</script>
```